# How can I get the Android phone speaker sound amplitude?

Tags: android

I'm trying to render a graph based on the music that is playing on Android phone. But I could not figure out a way to know how loud the song is currently playing. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```java
// getSystemService is a Context method
AudioManager audioManager =
    (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
// see other AudioManager.STREAM_* constants
int volume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Comment: i think this means the volume setting instead of the actual volume (or sound amplitude)?

Comment: @JasonHu you want to draw a sinusoid corresponding to the output sound from the device?

Comment: exactly. exactly.